# equalprg to use for Python

Tags: ide, indentation, whitespace, filetype-python

Python is whitespace dependent, and it can't be totally autoindented for that reason, but there are a lot of extra stuff that should be possible to do automatically to comply with PEP8.

Things like whitespaces around operators, two new lines before a class and one before a method, etc.

Is there any `equalprg` compatible utility for that? If not, how to program one?

Comment: PEP8 says: *"But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. [...] Some other good reasons to ignore a particular guideline: 1. When applying the guideline would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows this PEP. [...]"* ... PEP8 are guidelines only. The universe is complex. Code is complex. You can't make rules for every possible scenario, so this is why PEP8 are *guidelines*, and not *rules*. The whole point of Python is readability, and *especially* because of that ...

Comment: ... exceptions to PEP8 are sometimes required... Using an automated tool to "fix" the code style can't do these exceptions, and is a flawed concept ... If you want PEP8-compliant code, then type PEP8 compliant code, and when it makes sense, *make an exception*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [vim-autopep8](https://github.com/tell-k/vim-autopep8).

You'll need to `pip install autopep8` as well.

You can then call `:Autopep8` and it will fix most of the issues in your code. You can configure which issues to fix using either an inclusion list or an exclusion list, based on the errors in the [Pep8 error codes](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes).

It will also spit out a nice diff showing exactly what changed when you run it.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please provide more detail about how to use the plugin to accomplish the goal.